# jQuery Image Resize not working

Tags: jquery, html, image, resize, image-size

I am new here, I'm having a problem in my website recently, see, I made it so it would always be 10% of the image uploaded with jQuery, this is my HTML:

```
<body><!--Before this of course I had the DOCTYPE html-->
<div id="topbarUI" style="text-align: center; font-size: 25px;">
    <div id="profile" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px; margin-right: 10px; float: left;">
    <a href="DCV_Diego">
    <img style="border-radius: 15px;" id="profilepicfortopbar" src="Logo.png" alt="DCV's profile pic">
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

The image I want to change is the one that has the ID tag of `profilefortopbar`.
Here I have my jQuery(in my `script.js` file):

```
$("#profilepicfortopbar").each(function(){
    $(this).width($(this).width() * 0.1);
});
```

As you can see, it gets the current width of the image and makes it the same thing, but times 0.10, which is 10%.

It use to work for everything, but for some reason now it doesn't work, it keeps the same size of the original picture without multiplying by by 0.1.
**UPDATE**
The problem for some reason, was that I linked the js files on the bottom of the page, not on the top. This solved my problem! Thanks to u all anyways :D

Comment: Why are you using .each? You can only have one picture with that ID anyways.

Comment: I put that so if I add more pics with that ID, they all shrink :D @RenéRoth

Comment: IDs **have** to be unique. Use a class for this!

Comment: alrighty then, but that won't solve my question :(

Comment: I don't think your solution makes sense. Why not just set the values in CSS?

Comment: Because every time that picture will be different, and if I do it in CSS it will always be distorted, unless I get the width of the actual picture and make it 10% which is what I am doing. I've tried doing percentages in CSS and it didn't work either so....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var width = $("#profilepicfortopbar").width()*0.1;
     $("#profilepicfortopbar").css('width',width);
});
```

Or

```
$(function(){
    var width = $("#profilepicfortopbar").width()*0.1;
     $("#profilepicfortopbar").css('width',width);
});
```

**Update**
It's work. Maybe U wrong include jquery.
Try include:

```
$function(){
  alert('work');
});
```

Do U see alert ?

http://jsfiddle.net/LXW3H/

Comment: It's not when the window is resized, it's onload! None of them worked :( @Darex1991

Comment: YES IT WORKED (though it wasn't your JS, with my JS it was fine, look at update :D)